# how to resolve this .Net 3.5 warning/error?

Tags: c#, .net-3.5, compiler-errors

I have three machines. one installed VS2008 another two installed SDK6 and Framework3.5 (one of these two is a build machine).

When I use MSBuild to build our application, all of them get this warning:

> C:\WINDOWS\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Microsoft.Common.targets : warning MSB3245: Could not resolve this reference. Could not locate the assembly "WPFToolkit, Version=3.5.40128.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35". Check to make sure the assembly exists on disk. If this reference is required by your code, you may get compilation errors.

and the build machine comes with some errors:

> scsm\SCSM.cs(234,13): error CS1501: No
>   overload for method 'Invoke' takes '1'
>   arguments scsm\SCSM.cs(235,13): error
>   CS1501: No overload for method
>   'Invoke' takes '1' arguments
>   scsm\SCSM.cs(304,13): error CS1501: No
>   overload for method 'Invoke' takes '1'
>   arguments scsm\SCSM.cs(314,13): error
>   CS1501: No overload for method
>   'Invoke' takes '1' arguments
>   scsm\SCSM.cs(317,13): error CS1501: No
>   overload for method 'Invoke' takes '1'
>   arguments scsm\SCSM.cs(323,17): error
>   CS1501: No overload for method
>   'Invoke' takes '1' arguments
>   scsm\SCSM.cs(324,17): error CS1501: No
>   overload for method 'Invoke' takes '1'
>   arguments scsm\SCSM.cs(325,17): error
>   CS1501: No overload for method
>   'Invoke' takes '1' arguments

but other machines are passed without error. Resources are identical in those three machines.

searched online but cannot find answer. Anybody here can help me resolve this?
thanks

Comment: the piece of code which causes this warning may be interesting!

Comment: Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.dlgDNASequence.btnStart.IsEnabled = false));
Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() => this.dlgDNASequence.btnLogOff.IsEnabled = false));
above two are line 234 and 235.

Comment: you may want to append all lines which cause an error to your question (not necessarily as a comment :) )

Comment: btw ... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.threading.dispatcher.invoke.aspx ... i do not see an overload for `.Invoke(Action)`

Comment: @dittodhole: There is an overload `.Invoke(delegate, params args)`, which can be called with only the delegate (hence the `params`). But it only exists in 3.5 SP1, see my updated answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Could not locate the assembly "WPFToolkit, Version=3.5.40128.1, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35".

[WPFToolkit](http://www.codeplex.com/wpf) is not part of the .net Framework but a component that can be downloaded.

Did you download and copy the WPFToolkit-DLL to some place on the build machine where your project can find it? (either some directory set in your project references or the GAC)

---

> scsm\SCSM.cs(325,17): error CS1501: No overload for method 'Invoke' takes '1' arguments

In my experience, this problem can mean that you are missing SP1 for .net Framework 3.5.

EDIT: After seeing your code, I'm pretty sure this is the problem. `Dispatcher.Invoke(delegate, params object[] args)`, which you are calling here, was added in Framework 3.5 **SP1**, see [the MSDN page of this method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc647509.aspx):

> Supported in: 3.5 SP1, 3.0 SP2

Answer (score 2):

It looks like your machines are missing the [WPF Toolkit](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29117) assembly. For the smoothest results, include it in your version control system alongside your source code, and add references with the *Browse* tab in the *Add Reference* dialog in Visual Studio. Then you can be sure that it will be present and findable on any machine you fetch the source code onto in the future.

Answer (score 0):

The WPFToolkit sounds like you might want to install [this](http://wpf.codeplex.com/Release/ProjectReleases.aspx?ReleaseId=29117) (at a guess).

The `Invoke` sounds like a different dll version; perhaps missing an overload or extension method. Check the references are **identical** on the build server (or better: include references inside the project). It *could* also be the difference (say) between .NET 3.5 and .NET 3.5 SP1 (or similar), but it is hard to tell without seeing the offending line of code.